# Python3: copy / amend a file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I remotely run calculations on an HPC cluster: to do this I submit a batch file named 'psub':

```
#!/bin/bash
#MOAB -l walltime=48:00:0
#MOAB -j oe
#MOAB -N GULP-job
cd "$PBS_O_WORKDIR"
module load apps/gulp
#!/bin/bash
```

Using python 3: I would like to make several copies of this file: however, in doing so, I wish to alter the walltime specified, interactively. Nothing else in the file will change. 
However, my basic knowledge of programming is limiting my capability to work out how to go about doing this: I am able to make a copy of the file and append it.

A prod in the right direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick

```
with open(your_file_path) as f:
    lines = f.read_lines()
    lines[1] = '#MOAB -l walltime={0}'.format(new_walltime_str)

with open(your_file_path, 'w') as f:
    f.write('\n'.join(lines))
```

If you don't know which line the walltime is on, you can do other processing to find it. Does this answer your question?